# Uninstall Evince while retaining update and upgrade ability

Tags: upgrade, uninstall, evince

I tried to uninstall Evince but got a message that doing so would remove `ubuntu-desktop` which appears to be needed to update or upgrade the system.

Can we remove Evince and retain update and upgrade ability?

(Note that in case things are packaged differently in future, make sure no wanted packages are removed when Evince is uninstalled.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do an upgrade via the update-manager (or do-release-upgrade) it checks to ensure that you have ubuntu-desktop installed so you don't need to worry about it any more.

(Though this used to be a problem)

Answer (score 0):

One possible way around this is to create a fake, empty `evince` package with a very high version number, which will satisfy APT in thinking Evince is installed and thus keep ubuntu-desktop.

But like Jorge says, it's not absolutely necessary to keep the ubuntu-* metapackages around.